# Get string length and format it, first from integer to hexadecimal, and then, write it literally the same value inside a byte array

Tags: java, string, algorithm, hex, byte

I want to create a function in Java with the following prototype:

```
public byte[] serializeToByteArray(String message)
```

which receives a String as a parameter.

The function inside, have to calculate the message length, and then convert it to hexadecimal.
After converting to hexadecimal, it have to return two bytes with the length in hexadecimal.

Example 1:

- String length: 147
- Return value: byte[] = {0x00, 0x93}

Example 2:

- String length: 510
- Return value: byte[] = {0x01, 0xFE}

Example 3:

- String length: 10.001
- Return value: byte[] = {0x27, 0x11}

Comment: String length is int (4 bytes, up to 2^31 - 1), while you want to fit it into 2 bytes (2^16 - 1 = 65,535 bytes at most), is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Implement method to get 2-byte array representing length of the string
   *Note: check max length of the input string and throw `IllegalArgumentException`*

```java
static byte[] getLengthHex(String message) {
    int len = null == message ? 0: message.length();
    if (len > 0xFFFF) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input string is too long, its length = " + len);
    }
    return new byte[] {(byte)(len >> 8 & 0xFF), (byte)(len & 0xFF)};
}
```

2. Print the byte array using formatting:

```java
String[] tests = {
    "1".repeat(147),
    "2".repeat(510),
    "3".repeat(10_001)
};

for (String t : tests) {
    byte[] len = getLengthHex(t);
    System.out.printf("%5d -> 0x%02X 0x%02X%n", t.length(), len[0], len[1]);
}
```

Output:

```
  147 -> 0x00 0x93
  510 -> 0x01 0xFE
10001 -> 0x27 0x11
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. This is working perfectly fine.